# installed barcode scanner plugin with capacitor, pwa complain cordova not available

Tags: angular, cordova, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I am working on pwa with

`Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4

@angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4

@angular/cli                  : 7.2.4

@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Capacitor:

capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.0.0-beta.17

@capacitor/core           : 1.0.0-beta.17

System:

NodeJS : v10.0.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.7.0
   OS     : Linux 4.15
`installed the barcode`
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scannerionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner npm install --save @ionic`
and

`npx cap sync`
I installed the plugin in the module, but when I try to read a barcode, all that i get is an error `cordova not available, so I am stuck

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor doesn't support Cordova plugins on PWA yet

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/769

Comment: Github-Issue is still open as of 2022-11-01.